# How to fix "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()" in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have two time stamp columns, one is the start time and the other is the end time. I have calculated the difference and also stored it in another column in the dataset. Based on the difference column of the dataset, I want to fill in a value in another column. I am using for loop and if else for the same but upon execution, the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()" appears

```
   Time_df = pd.read_excel('filepath')

   print(Time_df.head(20))

   for index, rows in Time_df.head().iterrows():
         if(Time_df["Total Time"] < 6.00 ):
             Time_df["Code"] = 1

   print(Time_df.head(20))
```

In Total Downtime, wherever a less than 6 is encountered, it will put 1 in the column code. However, I get the error as stated in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

---

```
df["Code"]= np.where(df["Total Time"]<6.00,1,df["Code"])
```

---

**Explanation**:

```
#np.where(condition, choice if condition is met, choice if condition is not met)
#returns an array explained above
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix your code

```
   print(Time_df.head(20))

   for index, rows in Time_df.head().iterrows():
         if(rows["Total Time"] < 6.00 ):
             Time_df.loc[index,"Code"] = 1

   print(Time_df.head(20))
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me a lot. In `if (Time_df["Total Time"] < 6.00 )`, `(Time_df["Total Time"] < 6.00 )` is a series and Python does not know how to evaluate the series as a Boolean. Depending on what you want, but most likely you want to do:

```
Time_df.loc[Time_df["Total Time"] < 6.00, "Code"] = 1
```

which puts 1 in column "Code" wherever "Total Time" is < 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfn(row):
    if row['Total Time'] < 6:
        return 1


time_df['code'] = time_df.apply(lambda row: myfn(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is dangerous as it will put `None` where `'Total Time' >= 6`.